# Are both -ms-filter and filter used for gradients in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, vendor-prefix

I am using the following code, but now I don't know if I need to use both of these:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#46494F', endColorstr='#141A1E',GradientType=0);

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#46494F', endColorstr='#141A1E',GradientType=0)";}
```

What's making me more confused is that VS2010 reports the following message "Validation CSS 2.1 - filter is not a known property name."

Has anyone experienced similar issues using these? How about with IE9 and above? Are these still used or is that browser using new CSS standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` and `-ms-filter` are proprietary CSS properties invented by Microsoft for use with IE only, so the validation messages aren't an issue.

`filter` is used for IE older than 8, while IE8+ adopts the prefixed version, `-ms-filter`.

Comment: I don't know the whole story, but I do know that `filter` (also) works in IE8. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/UPuPR/

Comment: @thirtydot: That's what I found out too, but I don't know if it has anything to do with Visual Studio's warnings as OP reports. Maybe Visual Studio ignores vendor prefixes (they're nonstandard anyway), so Microsoft decided to go that route.

Comment: Thank you. How about new browsers like IE9. Does that browser still use -ms-filter or has it changed to something that lines up with CSS3?

Comment: @Hiroki: It uses `-ms-filter` (`filter` also works but like you said VS will complain).

Comment: @Hiroki - IE9 no longer supports `filter` or `-ms-filter` at all; you have to use CSS3 styles.

Comment: There's a crucial piece of information missing: a standard [`filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter) exists.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Microsoft replaced `filter` with `-ms-filter` in IE8 was because they needed to make incompatible syntax changes to it.

`-ms-filter` allows you to wrap the whole filter string in quotes, whereas the older `filter` style doesn't.

This is important because many filters include strings such as `progid:` (which is invalid CSS due to the colon). Including these filters in a `filter` style, without the quotes can cause other browsers to choke on the entire stylesheet.

IE9 has dropped support for both `filter` and `-ms-filter` entirely. If you want to use these effects in IE9 you have to use standard CSS3.

Comment: Partially right; it *was* invalid CSS.  Corrections: the reason they replaced `filter` with `-ms-filter` was to become CSS 2.1 compliant -- **all** proprietary extensions became vendor prefixed, `-ms-behavior`, `-ms-scrollbar-`, etc.  In CSS, invalid rules are to be ignored, no browser should "choke on the entire stylesheet" due to a single property value containing an extra `:`.

Comment: @Ande E -- I've seen Firefox 3.6 choke on a filter with `progid:` when I was working with a rotated element. FF ignored all styles after the filter. The only working solutions were to put the filter style as the last style in that CSS file or move it to an IE-specific CSS file. The `-ms-filter` was fine, because it could be wrapped in quotes, but the `filter` could not be fixed.

Comment: I don't doubt that one or two parsers may have choked on an IE filter, but that's really the parser's fault for being buggy and breaking on having a colon in the wrong place.  That's why I used the word *should* :-) I also won't dispute that switching to vendor prefixes provided an opportunity to fix the syntax, but the real reason was the CSS 2.1 compliant bragging rights (for which required both correct syntax and the vendor prefix).   You can see for yourself on [the blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx).

Comment: +1, but `filter` still does seem to work in IE9. http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ + http://fiddle.jshell.net/UPuPR/show/light/ (http://jsfiddle.net/UPuPR/)